# Correlation between outstanding hints in experimental particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, dark-matter, tevatron

The 115 GeV ATLAS Higgs with enhanced diphoton decays has [gone away](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/05/atlas-at-94pb-diphoton-hysteria-goes.html) but there are several other recent tantalizing hints relevant for particle physics, namely

- [CoGeNT's 7-8 GeV dark matter particle](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/05/cogent-sees-seasons-and-maybe-dark.html) that seems to support DAMA's and other signals
- [D0's fourth-generation top prime quark](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/04/d0-3-sigma-evidence-for-325-gev-top.html) that may be there at 325 GeV if a 3-sigma signal is right
- [CDF's "new" force Z prime boson](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/04/fermilab-cdf-new-force-press-conference.html) at 144 GeV which could be there if another 3-sigma bump is real
- [Tevatron's top-antitop asymmetry](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/04/fermilab-cdf-new-force-press-conference.html) above 400 GeV which seems very large
- [A related CDF top-quark anomaly](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/01/cdf-sees-another-top-quark-related.html)

and maybe others I missed. My question is simple:

> Is there some sensible theoretical basis (e.g. paper) that would simultaneously explain at least two of the observations above if they were real?

Comment: Something I saw recently: [arXiv 1104.4087](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4087) suggests a standard model compatible explanation for the CDF bump as an artifact of the selection criteria.

Comment: It's good but doesn't it explain just one of the bumps?

Comment: Yes, it only addresses the possible $Z'$.

Comment: The electron dipole measurement http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/05/electron-dipole-moment-below-1e-27-ecm.html seems like a strong negative hint, if it is as constraining as people say.

Comment: Couldn't ~100 GeV technipions and 800 GeV stable purely techincolor/QCD interacting technibaryons "explain" points 1 plus whichever other points?

Answer (score 4):

See arXiv:[1104.3145](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3145), [1103.6035](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.6035) and [1104.4127](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4127).

Comment: Funny two-step methods to link the observations, thanks, @Julius! ;-) A combination of a Z' interaction with dark matter is somewhat creative.

Comment: This answer would be much better if it gave a short overview about the contents of the papers.

Answer (score 2):

My NEW preference is the scalar with charge +4/3 that is being postulated as an explanation for the top-antitop asymmetry.

There are some published papers pursuing this idea, such as [arXiv:1103.2757](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2757) or [arXiv:0912.0972](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0972) and a couple of mini reviews [arXiv:1108.3341](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3341) and [arXiv:1107.0841](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0841).

As of today I can not tell which papers are the most relevant (see an explicit question [migrated from the old Theoretical Physics Stack Exchange site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27562/status-of-4-3-scalar-as-explanation-of-t-bar-t-asymmetry)). I think that they have a potential to explain some of the other observations because the charge in some GUT models has a contribution from B-L and a contribution from SU(2) chiral groups, so the +4/3 is nor really so exotic.

In any case, take my answer with a bit of salt. As the uppercase acrostic indicates in the first paragraph, I also have some personal motivations to support models along this line, because I tripped into these pesky +4/3 things [back in 2005](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0512065v1) and I really want to understand how they fit.