# status of +4/3 scalar as explanation of $t\bar t$ asymmetry

Tags: particle-physics, research-level, grand-unification

One of the early proposals for the Tevatron asymmetry on $t \bar t$ was a "fundamental diquark" with a charge (and hypercharge) +4/3, either in a triplet or a sextet colour. I am interested on the current status of this proposal:

Generically, has some particular model of been favoured in ulterior research?

For starters, you can see the short report in [JHEP 1109:097,2011](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/find/hep/www?eprint=arXiv:1107.0841), at the end of section 2, points 5 and 6. I only become aware of the survival of this hypothesis after seeing http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0477 last week.

Comment: Can you link to some published account of this proposal?

Comment: @Moshe done. But I am interested on any account, either unpublished (conferences or arxiv), published or rumoured.

Comment: I have confirmed with some authors that the field uses the normalization Q=T3+Y for the hypercharge. So hypercharge=4/3 is charge=4/3 if T=0